# Output Percentage with accordion in each of every multi-step forms once submitted

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am really new in web development. So I really need some guides, tips and tricks on how to do coding. So here's the details...

After I fill up my Yes and No checkboxes forms on each steps of a multi form steps, I want to have a grade on each steps. for example Leadership Development has a 12 Yes and 8 No and the system will calculate it's percentage from
(This is the pie chart) &  (This is the accordion)
0 to 49%                   Your leadership skills will need to be improved for your business to at least
survive.
50% to 70%                 You have middling leadership skills that could probably be sufficient for your
business to survive.
70% to 100%                You have very good leadership skills to help your organization grow.

How to show it's pie chart with percentage inside of it and beside the pie is an accordion which will also give details from the ratings.
Please I really need help on this one.

Here's the progress bar I made for an example

```
<style>
#output .accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-top: 152px;
}
#output .active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
#output .panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: #abaaaa;
  max-height: 0;
  color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
#output .accordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #d02a3e;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
#output .active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}
.progress-pie-chart {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ececec;
  position: relative;
}
.progress-pie-chart.gt-50 {
  background-color: orange;
}
.progress-pie-chart.red .ppc-progress-fill {
  background: red;
}
.progress-pie-chart.red span {
  color: red;
}
.progress-pie-chart.orange .ppc-progress-fill {
  background: orange;
}
.progress-pie-chart.orange span {
  color: orange;
}
.progress-pie-chart.green.gt-50,
.progress-pie-chart.green .ppc-progress-fill {
  background: green;
}
.progress-pie-chart.green span {
  color: green;
}

.ppc-progress {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 64px);
  top: calc(50% - 64px);
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  clip: rect(0, 128px, 128px, 64px);
}
.ppc-progress .ppc-progress-fill {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 64px);
  top: calc(50% - 64px);
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  clip: rect(0, 64px, 128px, 0);
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.gt-50 .ppc-progress {
  clip: rect(0, 64px, 128px, 0);
}
.gt-50 .ppc-progress .ppc-progress-fill {
  clip: rect(0, 128px, 128px, 64px);
  background: #E5E5E5;
}

.ppc-percents {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 111.30435px/2);
  top: calc(50% - 111.30435px/2);
  width: 111.30435px;
  height: 111.30435px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}
.ppc-percents span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.ppc-percents span cite {
  font-size: 35px;
}

.pcc-percents-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.progress-pie-chart {
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  margin-top: 115px;
}
</style>
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="progress-pie-chart" data-percent="24">
              <div class="ppc-progress">
               <div class="ppc-progress-fill"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="ppc-percents">
               <div class="pcc-percents-wrapper"><span>%</span></div>
              </div>
            </div>
             
            <div class="progress-pie-chart" data-percent="60">
              <div class="ppc-progress">
               <div class="ppc-progress-fill"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="ppc-percents">
               <div class="pcc-percents-wrapper"><span>%</span></div>
              </div>
            </div>
             
             
            <div class="progress-pie-chart" data-percent="95">
              <div class="ppc-progress">
               <div class="ppc-progress-fill"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="ppc-percents">
               <div class="pcc-percents-wrapper"><span>%</span></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-6 pt-4 pt-lg-0 align-items-stretch">
            <button class="accordion">Leadership Development System</button>
            <div class="panel">
              <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
            </div>

            <button class="accordion">Marketing System</button>
            <div class="panel">
              <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
            </div>

            <button class="accordion">Financial System</button>
            <div class="panel">
              <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
            </div>
```